# PyHook for Python 3.6

Tags: python, windows-10, pyhook

Hello does anyone have succeded in installing pyHook on the last python version

```
C:\Users\T>python --version
Python 3.6.4

C:\Users\T>pip install pyHook
Collecting pyHook Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pyHook

C:\Users\T>pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
pyHook-1.5.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Everythingi've try so far are not working at all.

Answer (score 2):

1) You're gonna wanna visit https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook download the version with "36" in the name.

2) Open cmd, git cmd, or git bash,

*On cmd change directory into the location where pip and the whl file are stored, type pip install (whl name with 36 in the version name)

*git cmd is the same thing

*On git bash, cd into the directory with the whl and pip and type ./pip install (whl name)

I had the same problem as you, but it turned out the only problem was the file version I was downloading. Make sure you're downloading the version that's compatible with the Python you're using.